# PHP in the phonegap application

Tags: php, cordova

I have to develop an Android application with the Phonegap framework and I need to use PHP. Does someone know if is possible using this language? In the affermative case in which way I can include it in my application? The official web site of the framework speaks only about the use of HTML,CSS and JavasScript and it doesn't speak at all of PHP. Help me, please it's important!

Answer (score 0):

## About webservers

That's not possible. In order to be able to interpret PHP files you would need a webserver such as apache, nginx or even PHP's built-in server.

Considering that, it would be an significant overhead in your phonegap application (and phonegap is already being criticized for it's performance) to run a webserver there.

## Using AJAX

However you can make ajax requests to a remote webserver via javascript, which will then respond properly and return data in a proper format so that you can process them in js (json for example)

## How the server side works

Your PHP application on the remote server has to be treated as an API. It's only there for taking requests and returning a proper response. It will not do any template rendering or dom manipulation (well you could return HTML if you wanted to, but that's not recommended since a DOM structure is bigger and will always take longer to load than a raw data format. And size matters when it comes down to mobile application development)

## How the client side works

All your phonegap app does is taking your users input, passing it to the server via ajax and  processing your response then.

Comment: It would possible read a file excel that is on a web server using ajax?
Take only the things that i want using  and transform it in a json ??

Comment: Sure. You can process the excel file serverside and respond with json.

Comment: Php actually has a built-in web server these days, and there's some projects out there for doing php on android. So it's possible at least.

Comment: Thanks! You definitely have a point. I'll add it to the answer. Still phonegap has no php installation what would leave it impossible to use php in a phonegap app.